# Media Queries and browser versions

Tags: css, animation, media-queries

I have produced an animation with SVG, @Keyframes and Animation.

I see that Chrome mobile browser only supports CSS Animation from v43..

How can I target only versions 43+ for the animation and have a fallback for older versions.. (Also for Safari) Is media queries the only way or are there other methods.

I don't seem to be able to find information on this.

Merci

Comment: v43? less than 3% in use, no need to worry about that, just use media query. REF: https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0

Comment: Stupid question, but why do you think you can solve the problem of animation not supported by using a media query?

Comment: Mr Lister.. Media Queries to target all versions after v43 and apply the animation.. all versions before to not have the animation

Comment: Hi Daniel H.  So I can use animation in my site but only with the risk that for some the site will be broken? I cannot use a fall back option?

Comment: It would appear that Modernizr is my solution